# Minimum variance portfolio problem

Tags: finance, variance

So the question asks:

There are N (N > 1) stocks with the same variance $σ^2$ and the same pairwise correlation coeﬃcient γ (i.e. $c_ij$ = γ for all i = j. γ is a given constant such that 0 ≤ γ < 1). Find the minimum variance portfolio.

So far I have: since all the assets play the same role (same variances, same covariances), so the weights have to be equal. As the weights add up to 1, each weight is 1/n.

But is there any way I can "compute” the weight instead of "stating" it? And how can I "show" the minimum variance portfolio in math?

Comment: This would really be better at quant.stackexchange.com. Finance questions are off topic here unless they don't require any knowledge of finance to answer and really are just math questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right to say that the optimal weight for each stock in the minimum variance portfolio of n stocks = $\frac{1}{n}$.  Given this

Variance of the minimum variance portfolio $=n\frac{\sigma^2}{n^2}+ {n\choose2} \frac{2\gamma\sigma^2}{n^2} = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.\frac{2\gamma \sigma^2}{n^2}$

If you simplify, you get

Variance of this portfolio $$= \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\left(1+(n-1)\gamma\right)$$

If you select n stocks with the same vairnce $\sigma^2$ then you don't need to compute optimal weight, because it is simply $\frac{1}{n}$ and you can compute the varince as stated above.